# Copy blocks to another screen MIT App Inventor

Tags: app-inventor

I published my app that has many screens, but now I want to go back and add a new feature to those screens. Is there any way that I can just create the new blocks once as a template and paste it to the new screens?

Comment: how many screens do you have?

Answer (score 3):

copy-paste of code blocks is not a good idea: instead of creating redundant code, you should think about a redesign of your app, see the following link for more details.

[Building apps with many screens](http://ai2.appinventor.mit.edu/reference/other/manyscreens.html)

> If it seems that your app requires a large number of screens, you
>   might think about redesigning it to not use so many.   For example,
>   suppose your app has to show several different screen images all with
>   the same functionality but each image having a different background. 
>   One way to code this would be to use a different App Inventor screen
>   for each image, each screen with its own background image.  With that
>   method,  you’d need as many screens as there are images.   But another
>   way to code this is to have only a single screen and change the screen
>   background.   Similar ideas apply to other kinds of elements:  If each
>   screen image has a label with its own text message, then rather than
>   having multiple screens, each with its own label, you could have a
>   single screen and a single label, and just change label’s text.

In **App Inventor**, you only can copy a complete screen, see the following method

[How to copy screens](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/app-inventor-developers-library/kHEFtUiJsQM/obxo_CKizTcJ) by Scott and a [video](http://amerkashi.wordpress.com/2014/06/10/ai-screen-manipulation/) by Hossein

**EDIT**: now there is the new [backpack cut-and-paste system](http://ai2.appinventor.mit.edu/reference/other/backpack.html)

> The Backpack allows you to carry around blocks throughout your project
>   repositories, allowing blocks to be transferred between projects and
>   between screens.  The contents of the Backpack persist throughout an
>   App Inventor session.  (NOTE:When you quit your App Inventor session
>   or refresh the App Inventor page in the browser, the Backpack will be
>   emptied -- i.e., re-initialized.)

Comment: I already copied screens to make the app, but now that I've done that I can't copy screens again because I will lose all the rest of the work. Its unfortunate that you can't copy blocks

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to copy objects (blocks, labels, pictures, lists, etc.) from one screen to another. See [Issue 2076](https://code.google.com/p/app-inventor-for-android/issues/detail?id=2076):

> It would be nice to be able to copy objects (labels, pictures, lists,
>   ect.) from one screen to another, theoretically the way it would
>   function is: on the right side on the components list, you could right
>   click on the component you would like to copy and press either
>   copy/paste or you could right click and press send to screen Y. Any
>   blocks related to these components on screen X would be sent with the
>   copied components to screen Y. This would be very useful/helpful
>   instead of trying to recreate multiple pages with the same layout and
>   block structure multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Drag block to your bag, if you want to use, just check your bag